# Why I can't name a user without mention it on Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to name a user that are previously mentioned, but I can't. This is the code:

```
@bot.command(name="kiss")
async def kiss(ctx, user):
    if ctx.message.channel.is_nsfw():
        with open ('kiss.json') as kg:
            kissgifs = json.load(kg)
        ksrandomchoice = random.choice(kissgifs)
        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.set_image(url=ksrandomchoice['kiss'])
        embed.add_field(name=f"{ctx.author.name} kissed {user.mention}", value="")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send("I'm not")
```

I tried using discord.User.display_name, but shows this: "<property object at 0x7f6a6106cef0>"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I'm trying to name a user that are previously mentioned, but I can't." What does that mean? Specifically, **what happens** when you run **the code that you have shown us**, and **how is that different** from what you want to happen? "I tried using discord.User.display_name, but shows this: "<property object at 0x7f6a6106cef0>"" What does this mean? How did you try it? Specifically, **what is the code that you tried** that has this change; **what happened** when you tried **that code**, and **what should happen instead**?

Comment: Anyway, the result that you show means that you tried to use a `property` from **the class itself, rather than** an instance. When documentation talks about `discord.User.display_name`, this **does not mean** "you should write code that says exactly `discord.User.display_name`"; it means "if you have a variable in your program that stores a `discord.User` instance, you can use `.display_name` on that".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code on line 2 :

```py
async def kiss(ctx, user):
```

Here, you declare a parameter `user`. I assume that you want users to mention other users, such as `.kiss @Someone`. But in order to do this, you have to hint Discord on the fact that the variable "`user`" actually represents an user. You can do this by precising the type of variable. It would look like this :

```py
async def kiss(ctx, user: discord.User):
```

Once done, you can use `user.name` in your code to name (or `user.mention` to mention) the user. Hope this helps !

Comment: `user.mention` mentions the user, not `user.name`

Comment: Yes, sorry I ment `user.name` to name the user :)